# Banco de dados insertando mesmo sem execução de script PHP

Tags: php

Salve!!!

Tenho um script PHP que quebra frases em array e insere palavra a palavra no BD. Até ai tudo certo, o lance começa quando mesmo sem o script estar ativo ou sessão ele permanece insertando loucamente, agora chegou a uma hora depois da interrupção do script.

Estou usando Postgres + PDO + PHP

```
private function InsertWordMessage( $id, $type, $text)
{
    $array = explode(' ',$text);

    foreach (  $array as $key ): 
       $this->insert->InsertWord($id,$type,$key);
    endforeach;
}
```

estou carregando as instâncias direto no construct e setando numa variável private, tanto da classe quanto do crud. O que posso estar deixando passar? Pois o volume nem é tão grande assim que fiz o teste e tenho conseguido insertar uma base de 4 a 5 linhas por segundo normalmente em outros codes no pg.

```
 $this->pack = json_decode($this->getToken($token,$secret,$fields), true);

    if(count($this->pack)<25)
    {$updated = 0;}
    else{$updated=1;}

    foreach($this->pack as $key => $value):
        if(!isset($value['picture'])) :  $value['picture'] = 'imagem/post.jpg' ; endif ;
        if(!isset($value['message'])) : $value['message']  = 'imagem incorporada' ; endif ;           
        if(!isset($value['permalink_url'])) : $value['permalink_url'] = 'not a link set' ; endif ;            
        if(!isset($value['name'])) : $value['name'] = 'not a name set' ; endif ;

        $idpost = $value['id'];
        $ps_idpage = $this->guide[0];
        $ps_date = \TimeConver::GMTtoUTC($value['created_time']['date'], "Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ps_categoty = $value['type'];
        $ps_picture = $value['picture']; 
        $ps_name = $value['name'];
        $ps_message = $value['message'];
        $ps_link = $value['permalink_url'];

        $this->getSentiment($ps_message);

        $this->insert->InsertUserAtivity($idpost,'POST',$ps_date,$this->sentiment) ;

        if ($ps_message != 'imagem incorporada' or ' ') : $this->InsertWordMessage($idpost, 'POST', $ps_message) ;
        else : $sent =  $this->InsertWordMessage($idpost, 'POST',$ps_name) ;  
        endif ;         

        $this->insert->InsertPost($idpost,$ps_idpage,$ps_date,$ps_categoty,$ps_picture,$ps_name,$ps_message,$ps_link) ;

        $ps = new Executor();        
        $ps->PostSummary($idpost)->CollectPostSummary();
    endforeach;

    do
    {               
        $this->pack = $this->response;
        if(count($this->pack)<25)
        {$updated=0;}
        else{$updated=1;}

        foreach($this->pack as $key => $value):
            if(!isset($value['picture'])) :  $value['picture'] = 'imagem/post.jpg' ; endif ;
            if(!isset($value['message'])) : $value['message']  = 'imagem incorporada' ; endif ;           
            if(!isset($value['permalink_url'])) : $value['permalink_url'] = 'not a link set' ; endif ;            
            if(!isset($value['name'])) : $value['name'] = 'not a name set' ; endif ;

            $idpost     = $value['id'];
            $ps_idpage  = $this->guide[0];
            $time       = $value['created_time']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $ps_date    = \TimeConver::GMTtoUTC($time, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $ps_categoty= $value['type'];
            $ps_picture = $value['picture']; 
            $ps_name    = $value['name'];
            $ps_message = $value['message'];
            $ps_link    = $value['permalink_url'];

            $this->getSentiment($ps_message);

            $this->insert->InsertUserAtivity($idpost,'POST',$ps_date,$this->sentiment) ;

            if ($ps_message != 'imagem incorporada' or ' ') : $this->InsertWordMessage($idpost, 'POST', $ps_message) ;
                else : $sent =  $this->InsertWordMessage($idpost, 'POST',$ps_name) ;  
            endif ;         

            $this->insert->InsertPost($idpost,$ps_idpage,$ps_date,$ps_categoty,$ps_picture,$ps_name,$ps_message,$ps_link) ;

            $ps = new Executor();        
            $ps->PostSummary($idpost)->CollectPostSummary();               
        endforeach;
    }
    while($this->response = $this->fb->next($this->response));            
}
```

Comment: Sem vc chamar ele insere registros? vc tem algum agendamento/crontab chamando esse arquivo? coloca tbm o código que chama `InsertWordMessage()`

Comment: Me parece que seu script faz um insert por palavra, e não por frases. Ele quebra por espaço. É essa mesmo a intenção?

Comment: Add  o código acima, não tem nenhum agendamento. Esse code é fragmento de um bot de facebook que fica 24 horas rodando, o que me preocupa é que preciso das palavras em tempo real do que for entrando para sistema de alerta e ficou rodando por quase 1 hora sem nada rodando no script.

Comment: Sim Bacco a intenção é essa, ele faz diversos insert, esse de palavra uso para recorrencia, para plotar word cloud